# Server side omniture page tracking

Tags: adobe-analytics

we use omniture to track page visits in our site. It works well. However, we have a scenario where we have some redirect links that redirect to a different website over which we have no control.

Example, I am on page A and it has a link to a redirect page B (in the same domain). However, when user clicks on the link to page B, the page B redirects the user at the server side to a different website.

How can we track page visits for page B? I tried using s.tl method. However, is there a way to track redirect page B visit similar to a regular page in site site?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your situation. If you do not have access to add client-side code to page B, then you likely do not have access to track page B with server-side code. The best you can do is on page A, track the click on the link that takes you to page B, onclick of the link (before the redirect happens)

Comment: Hi Crayon, thank you for the reply. YesI am trying on the lines similar to your update. However we do have access to the sever side code as the page B is in our domain and we do the redirect during the processing of Page B.

Comment: I admit I'm further confused.. you have server-side access to Page B, but can't output the regular javascript implementation?

Comment: Hi Crayon, sorry if I am confusing. We have server side access during Page B load, but during the server side load of page B, it is redirected to the external site. So, basically, there is no HTML rendering for page B.

Comment: Okay well my first suggestion would be for you to do client-side click tracking on the link before the redirect.  The 2nd option (server-side) involves using the [Data Insertion API](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/data-insertion-api/index.md) which is a bit more complex and will require you to do some client-side coding on Page A anyways, to get some stuff (e.g. the visitor id)

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the first option to do client side tracking of the link before the redirect.